# SQL Server 2008: how to concatenate values in statement "replace value of"

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008

Here is my test SQL:

```
declare @Table table (strField nvarchar(6), xmlField xml)
insert into @Table values ('123456', '<root><Node value="node value"/></root>')
select * from @Table
```

Now what I'm trying to figure out is how to update value of XML field here and assign a new value to it that would be a concatenation of two pieces. Here is what I got so far:

```
update @Table
set xmlField.modify('replace value of (/root/Node/@value)[1] 
                     with "new node value" + sql:column("strField")')
```

But this syntax is not good enough for SQL Server. I googled for solution but didn't find any good. I wonder if there is a way at all to do what I'm trying to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `concat("new node value", sql:column("strField"))`?

See the [concat function (XQuery)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190972.aspx) from the SQL Server 2008 documentation.

Happy coding.